# Share Javascript Variable on two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I have A page a.aspx and another page b.aspx.
I am using http://flowplayer.org overlay to open b.aspx on page a.aspx.
Now I want to use a variable (java script) on page b.aspx which is declared on page a.aspx.
Is it possible to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is "No".

If you are having .aspx pages inside other container (Frame) then you can share it by having your variable as part of the parent page.

Other options are

1. Client side - Cookies (persistent/non-persistent) depending on your requirement
2. Server side - using session (as suggested by Hemant Metalia)

Comment: Let me explain the situation. I wanted to use preloaded images on the b.aspx.

Comment: what do you mean by preloaded image? are you converting binary data into image on the client side or image is just a resource file residing on the server (uri)?

Comment: I have a situation where on first page I want to load the second page on a div. like a model popup I am using http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html api. And on the second page I have a div which has background image and on td click the image get changed.The click event of the td is written on the first page. but for the slow connection it takes some moment to change the background image. So I wanted to pre load image which I was able to do. using some suggestion by this site.

Comment: But the function called when the second page document.ready() method called. And then only I can created the Image array. Now My function which is written on the first page don't get the array which is created on the second page document.ready() function.

Comment: I there any other solution of doing this. I don't want to write the function on the second page because it loaded again and again. So I wanted to keep most of the function and css on the first page.

Comment: Can you suggest me any better way of doing this.

Comment: @krshekhar, can you please create a new question and post the code that you have written so far (html + javascript + any server side code).

Comment: I am posting a new question. Kindly give me some suggestion

Answer (score 3):

you can use session for it refer this http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

another way is to use `windows.location` for that see http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111/A-Quick-Tutorial-on-JavaScript-Variable-Passing.htm